# How to obtain a number from rsa encrypted message

Tags: python, rsa

Recently, i've been playing with RSA algorithm. The thing that i don't understand is that, whenever i encrypt a message i obtain a big number, right?:

> "70796684736487236029913292120872639995"

Then, why some encrypted messages have numbers and letters like this one:

> "10d5f3808d5de8c4e31145e77830a93c2"

How can i possibly convert this mix of numbers and letters back into a big number and so, decrypting it? (Python).

Comment: The question is good, but would be greatly improved if you linked some research you've done to answer this.  For example, what are the numbers used in RSA?  What have you done with non-Python programs to look into a public key, etc?

Comment: I guess your first encrypted message is a number in decimal representation and the second encrypted message is in hexadecimal representation. To convert from hex to decimal you can do `int("10d5f3808d5de8c4e31145e77830a93c2", 16)`

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i needed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question, and it has been answered in the comments.

Comment: Note that the RSA algorithm is using (big) numbers, however, the [RSA standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017) handles binary plaintext and binary ciphertext (of the same size as the modulus in bytes). Hexadecimals are a textual representation of those bytes.